# Access configuration file mentioned in spring boot application.properties after creating the .jar for App engine deployment

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am facing big trouble in deploying a spring boot application in GCP AppEngine with cloud Postgres as a database. Earlier I was using tcp connection jdbc with IP whitelisting to access the database, which worked fine during testing but after deploying into Appengine it didn't warmed up due to `sslsocket timed out`. So after a bit of digging, I found for standard appengine runtime to connect a cloud Postgres I have to use postgres socket factory

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

with
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///{REDACT}?cloudSqlInstance={REDACT}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user={REDACT}&password={REDACT}`  in application.properties.

But GCP needs to verify the connection from the key generated from the service account with specific privileges which has been added to the application.properties.
`spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:gcloud.json`

But in java the built jar file can't access the json, nor the deployed appengine instance.
Here's the error

[Screenshot error in App engine][1]

app.yaml

```yaml
runtime: java11
```

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.19</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any reply would be of great help. Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEV2r.png

Answer (score 0):

With App Engine you don't need to use a service account key file. You can rely on the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) that provides automatically App Engine service account credential. Service account is not customizable for now, but should change in 2021! It name is the following: `<projectID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Be sure that this service account has [enough Cloud SQL permissions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/roles-and-permissions) (by default, it has Editor role on the project, and have enough (and even too much!!) permissions)

So, use the [Cloud SQL App Engine connector in the `app.yaml` file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard) to set up the connection with Cloud SQL and open a socket (to connect with socket factory) in your code